# How to export in nextjs without regenerate the elements

Tags: django, next.js, django-templates

I have a project with nextjs and I had to get output from it
Now, if I want to make a change in the created html pages, I have to go to the chunks folder and edit the js file related to it, but I don't want this to happen because I want to set it with Django variables, and I don't want it to be related in any way. I can also use restful
Thankful

Also, I tried rendering on the server side and set webpack to false in the nextjs configuration, but no results were obtained.